# What does 打着饱嗝 and 嫌缸沿脏 and 踩上去蹲在上面 mean in the novel 活着 p.7?

Tags: translation, meaning-in-context

I've started reading 活着 which is supposedly a good book for new readers.  However, I'm having trouble understanding this part on page 7 (my translation).  [*Warning*: it's about poop.]

> 我爹走到了城里，城里人见了都叫他先生。我爹是很有身份的人，可他拉屎时就像个穷人了。他不爱在屋里床边的马桶上拉屎，跟牲畜似的喜欢到野地里去拉屎。...
> My father goes to the city, where city-folk meet him and call him "Mister".  My father is a very esteemed person, but when he poops he's just like a poor person.  He does not like to poop in the toilet in his room.  Like livestock, he likes to go into the wilderness to poop.
>
> ... 每天到了傍晚的时候，我爹**打着饱嗝**，那声响和青蛙叫唤差不多，走出屋去，慢吞吞地朝村口的粪缸走去。
>
> Every day at dusk, my father [eats a lot and burps (??)], and it sounds like a frog's croak.  Leaving his room, he goes very slowly towards village entrance manure vat.
>
> 走到了粪缸旁，他**嫌缸沿脏**，就抬脚**踩上去蹲在上面**。我爹年纪大了，屎也跟着老了，出来不容易，那时候我们全家人都会听到他在村口嗷嗷叫着。
> After reaching the manure vat, he [dislike vat dirtiness (??)], raises his foot, steps over and [crouches on top of it (??)].  My dad is elderly, and his poop is also old, and it doesn't come out easily.  At that time, our family members can all hear him at the village entrance shout "ao ao".

**Question**: What does 打着饱嗝 and 嫌缸沿脏 and 踩上去蹲在上面 mean?

I translated 村口 to "village entrance", but I'm not so sure about that too.

Comment: Curious to know why you were told 活着 is good for new reader. It might be hard to understand some local usage of words. :)

Comment: I’ve seen a few recommendations for this book online; it’s the one that’s most commonly recommended. I also used some web app to determine how much <=HSK4 material is in it, so it should be reasonable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

打饱嗝 = let out a (after full meal) belch

打着饱嗝 = letting out a (after full meal) belch

~

嫌 = dislike

缸沿 = edge of the (opening of) crock

脏 = dirty

嫌缸沿脏 = disgusted by the edge of the opening of the crock being dirty

~

踩上去 = step upon

蹲在上面 = crouch on top of

踩上去蹲在上面 = step upon and crouch on top of

> He was disgusted by the edge of the crock opening being dirty, didn't want to sit on it, so he stepped upon the edge of the crock and crouched on top of it (to take a dump)